# Write text and Print in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have the following code:

```
package com.zetcode

import java.io.File

fun main() {

    val fileName = "P3.txt"

    val content = File(P3.txt).readText()

    println(content)
}
```

My goal is to write a code in kotlin that reads the text file (P3.txt) and prints its content. I know there is something wrong because I keep receiving "unresolved reference.

Answer (score 0):

`File` takes a string as input, you should change the line:

```
val content = File(P3.txt).readText()
```

to

```
val content = File("P3.txt").readText()
```

The difference is that without the quotes, kotlin thinks `P3` is a reference that is not declared anywhere and you get the error you've mentioned.

Comment: adding the quotations sure did the trick but would this code still work if my P3.text is found in my desktop? You see, when I ran the code I received this error:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: P3.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
 at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readText(FileReadWrite.kt:125)
 at kotlin.io.FilesKt__FileReadWriteKt.readText$default(FileReadWrite.kt:125)
 at com.zetcode.P4Kt.main(P4.kt:9)
 at com.zetcode.P4Kt.main(P4.kt)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using a Mac as opposed to a Windows

Comment: that's a completely different issue. The file needs to exist otherwise you'll receive that error. You need to make sure you deal with the error or guarantee the file is always there. How you do it depends highly on your use cases.